# Rails I18n.fallbacks and enforce_available_locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, rails-i18n

I have to set the locale in a specific controller action like this:

```
def my_action
  I18n.locale = get_locale_from_this_object(@object)

  ...
end
```

The problem is that the object doesn't always refer to a locale that is available.

**Example:**

```
@object.locale = 'pt'
```

but

```
I18n.available_locales # => [:en, :"pt-BR"]
```

I thought that maybe the **I18n.fallbacks** could help, but I think they don't have any effect if I have:

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = true
```

That said, is there anyway I can make the locale **:pt** fallback to the locale **:'pt-BR'**? Or will I have to create a custom method for this?

*Obs: I'm not trying to get the locale from the http accepted languages.*